# Running mocha tests with node.js and xunit break with console.log

Tags: xml, node.js, jenkins, mocha.js, xunit

I currently have my mocha tests that run on top of node.js integrated with jenkins. The problem is when I use xunit to parse my results, a lot of console.log statements in my code (particularly for displaying more information about errors with network connectivity, user auth, etc). The problem with this is that when I use an xml reporter with mocha, the statements from console.log show up and break the parsing of the final xml result set.

Is there currently a smart way of having my console.log statements in my tests for when I run them manually on the CLI vs when they're executed via Jenkins and require clean XML that xunit expects to parse?

Answer (score 1):

When I used Jenkins, I set my code so that it would work differently whether it is running in Jenkins or not by checking for the `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable. (Among all the variables that Jenkins sets, this one seemed most distinctive and less likely to be accidentally set by something else.) If this variable was set, my code would assume it is running in Jenkins and act accordingly.

For instance this would set `log` to be equivalent to `console.log` outside of Jenkins and a function that does nothing when in Jenkins:

```
var jenkins = (process.env.JENKINS_HOME !== undefined);

var log = !jenkins ? console.log : function () {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you're running in an interactive terminal with `process.stdout.isTTY`. In case it's not a tty, you can set `console.log` to an empty function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to console.log you can write debugging statements and all the other information you need to console.error. Jenkins console output will display this information similar how it displays information from console log, and generated xml will be kept intact.